# Generalizations of Birkhoff's HSP Theorem

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, universal-algebra, lattice-theory, algebraic-systems

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be the class of algebraic structures of some fixed type satisfying some sentence $\phi$.  Birkhoff's HSP theorem says that $\mathbf{C}$ is closed under homomorphisms, subalgebras and products if and only if $\phi$ is equivalent to some universally quantified conjuction of equations.  In the following article -

Properties preserved under algebraic construction.
Author: R. C. Lyndon.
Journal: Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 65 (1959), 287-299.
http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1959-65-05/S0002-9904-1959-10321-9/

Lyndon refers to an "obvious" HD theorem at the top of p293 (as opposed to Birkhoff's UHD(=HSP) theorem) which I think means that the same result holds if $\mathbf{C}$ is only closed under homomorphisms and products, except that we now allow existential as well as universal quantifiers.  Let us say we weaken the assumption on $\mathbf{C}$ just a little more, and assume that the homomorphisms considered only come from coordinate functions on products, i.e. what if we only assume that $\mathbf{C}$ satisfies

$X\times Y\in\mathbf{C}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad X\in\mathbf{C}\textrm{ and }Y\in\mathbf{C}$

(and the same for infinite products, although I think this already follows from the above finite product assumption).  What kind of sentence must $\phi$ now be equivalent to?

Answer (score 8):

It is true that a first-order sentence, which is preserved by finite direct products, is also preserved by infinite direct products; see Corollary 6.7 of S. Feferman and R. L. Vaught, The first order properties of products of algebraic systems, Fund. Math. 47 (1959), 57-103.

In H. J. Keisler's terminology, a first-order sentence is called a *product sentence* if it holds in a product $X\times Y$ whenever it holds in $X$ and $Y$, a *factor sentence* if it holds in $X$ and $Y$ whenever it holds in $X\times Y$. If memory serves, rather complicated characterizations of product sentences and factor sentences were found by Keisler in the 1960s; the work of Keisler's student J. M. Weinstein may also be relevant. I'm pretty sure the results or at least the references are in the book *Model Theory* by C. C. Chang and H. J. Keisler. (I happen to have at hand a reference to Weinstein's dissertation: Joseph M. Weinstein, First order properties preserved by direct product, University of Wisconsin, Madison, 1965.)

Now, if you wanted to know which first-order sentences are preserved by *reduced* products (direct products reduced modulo a filter on the index set, like ultraproducts but with any old filter instead of an ultrafilter), the answer (also due to Keisler) is very nice: a first-order sentence is preserved by proper reduced products if and only if it's logically equivalent to a Horn sentence. ("Proper" here means that the index set is nonempty and the filter is a filter of nonempty sets; if you want to include the improper reduced product, insert "strict" before "Horn sentence".) I'm sure this is discussed in the Chang-Keisler book.

Comment: Great, thanks for the references.  I couldn't find the results themselves in Chang and Keisler's book, although they do say there that Weinstein's thesis contains some complicated characterization of product sentences, as you mentioned, and exercise 5.2.23** is about characterizing factor sentences, which is explained in more detail in Keisler's article "Some Applications of Infinitely Long Formulas".

Comment: However, I would still be curious to know if there is some nice description of sentences that are both a product AND a factor sentence.  After all, Birkhoff's HSP theorem and Lyndon's HD(=HP) theorem show that adding assumptions to "product sentence" can lead to simpler characterizations.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers

Comment: Good question. If anybody knows I guess it would be [Keisler](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/). Maybe you should ask the great man himself: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/

Comment: In the same vein as Birkhoff and Lyndon, Weinstein proved that a first-order sentence is preserved by direct products AND unions of chains if and only if it's logically equivalent to a universal-existential Horn sentence. This was (if I remember right) the main result of his dissertation; it's probably mentioned in Chang and Keisler's book.